# Determining a transition probability matrix

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

If I have that $X_n$ is a  two-state Markov chain whose transition probability matrix is:

$P = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} \alpha & 1-\alpha\\ 1-\beta & \beta \\\end{smallmatrix} \right)$

Then $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$ is a Markov chain having the four states (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1).  How would I determine the transition probability matrix?  I appreciate all of the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the possible transistions are those for which $Z_{n,2} = Z_{n+1, 1}$, ie
$$
(0,0) \to (0, 0)\\
(0,0) \to (0, 1)\\
(1,0) \to (0, 0)\\
(1,0) \to (0, 1)\\
(0,1) \to (1, 0)\\
(0,1) \to (1, 1)\\
(1,1) \to (1, 0)\\
(1,1) \to (1, 1)
$$

and for instance the transition $(0,1)\to (1,1)$ has probability
$$
P(X_{n+1} = 1, X_{n} = 1 | X_{n} = 1, X_{n-1} = 0)
= 
P(X_{n+1} = 1, X_{n} = 1 | X_{n} = 1)
$$
because of the Markov property,
$$
= P(X_{n+1} = 1| X_{n} = 1) = \beta
$$

Comment: so would the matrix be in terms of numbers or in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: can't you compute it with the help of my message?

Comment: @user141745 the matrix would be in terms of $\alpha$, $1-\alpha$, $\beta$, and $1-\beta$ since that is what was given in the two-state Markov matrix. If it's helpful to think about it that way then consider these terms as probabilities such that $\sum_j p_{ij}=1$.